# Can i share Microsoft sway with anonymous users

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to share  Microsoft sway with anybody? So like the way google slides work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we could share the sway with **[Anyone with a link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-your-sway-1cf853b8-ef7e-46b0-b704-003e58d28998)**, then embed this sway with **[Embed web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8)** in SharePoint online page:

[image]

[image]